# Am I allowed to make changes in the accepted paper before sending it to publication

Tags: journals

I have a paper accepted in an Applied Mathematics journal. My question is that should I submit the accepted version to editors for publication or I can make some minor corrections (for example, some remarks to a Theorem in the paper. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What do you mean by "bugs"?**

Do you mean spelling or grammar mistakes, an error in the reference list, etc.?
Or do you mean actual bugs in the algorithm or code?

If you mean the first one, it is OK to handle this in the proofing stage. Check how the journal does proofing; typically, the journal generates a PDF in their own typesetting system, and you make comments on this PDF with corrections. Here you can fix language mistakes, update references etc. but you should not add substantial new content.

If you mean you have found actual bugs in algorithm, code or results, the ethical thing would be to tell the editor exactly what you have found and let him/her decide.

Comment: I meant the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, your situation is like this:

Your paper has been accepted, i.e. you got the reply from the editor that the paper is **accepted as is** (i.e. no minor or major revision) and requested you to send the paper to the production staff in some way.

If this is correct, then the editor will not be involved in the production process and hence, you should submit the paper **as it was** since this is what has been accepted. As said, there will be the proof-reading stage at which you can take care of small things (if they haven't been taken care of already).

If you paper has been accepted *pending a minor revision*, then you can still make changes that have not been requested by some referee but you should says this is your response letter (a simple "Furthermore, some minor edits to the formulation have been made and some typos have been corrected."), since in this case the editor will still see the paper again before final acceptance.